# Postgres stored procedure call from java, table to return

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures, jdbc, java-stored-procedures

I made a Postgres stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetUser(ipUserId integer)
RETURNS setof users AS $$
BEGIN
  IF ipUserId is null THEN
    return query select * from users A order by modifieddate desc;
  END IF;
  return query select * from users where iduser = ipUserId;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I tried to use it in java like this:

```
    StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("GetUser").
            registerStoredProcedureParameter("ipUserId",
                    Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("users",
                    List.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
            .setParameter("postId", 1);
```

or

```
 StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("GetUser")
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1,void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2,Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .setParameter(2, ipIdUser);
```

**I want to store the result in a List.**

What and how should i do, because i'm getting all kind of errors?

Update :

Those are the errors :

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.convert(OutputsImpl.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.<init>(OutputsImpl.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureOutputsImpl.<init>(ProcedureOutputsImpl.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.outputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:663)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getResultList(ProcedureCallImpl.java:751)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A CallableStatement was executed with an invalid number of parameters
```

Comment: Post the details of your error message.

Comment: The second call isn't going to work because you're not using a ref_cursor in your function (and to be picky, you're not calling a stored procedure, you're calling a function. stored procs are new in pgsql 11 and don't return anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a much simple solution, just make a SQL Query to call the procedure with hibernate.

```
    String SqlString = "select * from GetUser({0})";

    if (ipIdUser == null )
        SqlString = MessageFormat.format(SqlString, "NULL");
    else
        SqlString = MessageFormat.format(SqlString, ipIdUser);

    LOGGER.info("SqlSting =" + SqlString);

    return entityManager.createNativeQuery(SqlString, User.class)
            .getResultList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using CallableStatement. 
Assuming that your Connection var is OK:

```
CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("{call SCHEMA.PROCEDURE_NAME (?, ?)}");
stmt.setInt(1, custom_var);
stmt.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.INTEGER);
stmt.execute();
```

To get result: `stmt.getInt(3); stmt.getString(4)`

If you can't succeed try using JdbcTemplate:

```
SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(this.jdbcTemplate).withSchemaName(SCHEMA).withProcedureName(PROC);
MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
params.addValue("ipUserId", custom_var);
Map out = call.execute(params);
```

To get single result: `Integer.parseInt("" + out.get("OUT_PARAM_NAME")); (String) out.get("OUT_PARAM_NAME2"));`

Or you can save all the result in a list to work on it later:

```
SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(this.jdbcTemplate);
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = call.getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(PROC_STRING, new Object[] { param1, param2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `getResultList` on `StoredProcedureQuery`? This avoids having to do the string manipulation.

```
List<User> users = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("GetUser")
  .registerStoredProcedureParameter("ipUserId", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
  .setParameter("ipUserId", ipIdUser)
  .getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have a table valued function that happens to map to an actual table, so the [approach using the JPA native query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52665303/521799) is elegant too, but perhaps your projection is something different, or you return multiple nested data structures, arrays, etc, where working with JPA might be tricky.

[jOOQ generates code for all of your procedures, including table valued functions](https://blog.jooq.org/postgresqls-table-valued-functions/). For example, you'll have a `Routines` class containing a `getUser` method, which you can query like this:

```java
Result<GetUser> result = Routines.getUser(configuration, 1);
```

You can also use the table valued function as an actual table in the query, like this:

```java
Result<GetUser> result = ctx.selectFrom(GETUSER(1)).fetch();
```

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.